# My laptop has USB 3.0 but all physical ports are USB 2.0?

Tags: windows-10, usb, laptop

It looks like there is something wrong with mapping here.
I'm not so sure about this but my  ASUS N46VZ laptop (released in 2012) does have USB 3.0 (checked using Device Manager), however by using the tool `UsbTreeView` to check which physical port using USB 3.0 (of course with a testing USB), I can see that all the physical ports are just USB 2.0

[image]

As you can see the screenshot above, all physical ports I've tried (with my USB) go under that `Enhanced Host Controller` in the red section.

There are no ports going under the `eXtensible Host Controller`.

I've just bought the Samsung T7 Portable SSD and its read/write speed is limited (max at about 33 MB/s) by the USB 2.0 ports on my laptop, already tried with all the physical ports. But as you can see (from the snapshot above), my laptop does have USB 3.0, it's just unusable because of some wrong mapping here (not mapped to any physical ports).

How could I fix this issue? thanks!

Device Manager

[image]

With Samsung T7 plugged-in:

[image]

**RESOLVED**

I saw that my Windows has some updates so I tried restarting it (with my external devices plugged-in), and somehow the USB 3.0 ports now work, even for my optical mouse (which was connected as USB 2.0 before):

[image]

Comment: Only USB2 devices are seen on your screenshot. Please, provide the same screenshot with the USB3 device attached. Also, check the manual of your laptop as to where USB3-capable ports are located. Probably, those are USB-C ports?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I've added screenshot when plugging the Samsung T7, I hope that T7 is kind of a USB 3.0 device?

Comment: I assume you are using a C-to-A cable. Does the cable you are using come with the SSD? (Like inside the box; not some retailer gift?) If not, are you sure it is a 3.x cable?

Comment: @TomYan yes, I'm using a C-to-A cable, that cable comes with the Samsung T7 I bought. Thanks

Comment: @TomYan do you mean that the cable can matter if the USB 3.0 controller is used by Windows when connecting my device? I'm not so sure about that cable's capability but it comes with the T7 I bought (inside the box).

Comment: If you connect it with a 2.0 cable it will be recognized as a 2.0 device (or well, "High Speed", instead of "SuperSpeed"). But you would hardly get a 2.0 cable from Samsung.

Comment: Just in case – look inside the 'A' end of the cable. Does it have 5 extra pins at the very back (behind the 4 main pins)? If it doesn't, then it's not a USB 3 cable. (Also, with old laptops, the extra USB 3 pins sometimes don't make good contact and the device ends up making a USB 2 connection over the 4 main pins...)

Comment: @user1686 yes, it does have a 5 extra pins at the very back, looks like it's a genuine USB 3.2-support cable from Samsung. Actually my laptop has one port that can recognize my testing USB (which is just 2.0) but somehow can't recognize my Samsung T7. I guess that's the only USB 3.0 on my laptop but it's failed somehow :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, each physical 3.x port will appear twice in USB explorers: once as EHCI (USB 2.0) and once as xHCI (USB 3.x). When a USB 2.0 device is connected, it will appear as connected to the EHCI port and xHCI will appear to have nothing connected. Similarly, USB 3.x devices will appear in the corresponding xHCI port and EHCI will have nothing connected.

Your method will only work reliably when testing with a USB 3.x device.